# Resizing Text while SpeechSynthesizer is speaking C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am wondering if anyone can tell me how to basically resize a label or image when the .NET Microsoft Speech Synthesizer is speaking.

The goal is to make the text in the center bigger and smaller as the synthesizer speaks. so when there are high pitches then then text is bigger and lower pitches text is smaller etc.

any ways to accomplish this while the synthesizer is speaking?
I have already tried using the SpeakStarted and SpeakComplted events to resize text but it is static - it doesn't change as the synthesizer is speaking.

I would really appreciate any help.

I am programming this in C# WPF.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You may have to synthesize to a wave file then play the file while looking at the levels.  NAudio may be useful here.

Comment: Is there no other way? This seems like it would slow down the application if it is constantly converting speech to wave files and then storing them somewhere. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Even if I did make the speech into a wave file, how would I change the text size?

Comment: Is wpf, so with a binding would be where I would start,  try resizing text with a slider and then go from there

Answer (score 0):

How's about subscribing to the SpeakProgress or StateChanged events? SpeakProgress is 'Raised after an individual word of a prompt is spoken.', StateChanged offers options on 'Paused, Ready or Speaking'.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362940%28v=office.14%29.aspx

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

// Add a handler for the SpeakProgress event.
synth.SpeakProgress += 
new EventHandler<SpeakProgressEventArgs>(synth_SpeakProgress);

// Write each word and its character position to the console.
static void synth_SpeakProgress(object sender, SpeakProgressEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Speak progress: {0} {1}", e.CharacterPosition, e.Text);
}
```

Comment: OK, this is cool - but how would I change the font size so that it makes the text look like it is getting bigger and smaller in conjunction with the speech?

Comment: Completely dependent on your implementation. If you update your question with the XAML you're working with I'll see if I can produce a more specific answer.